# Login screen switched to Gnome3 when i istalled other Desktop environement. Can't find how to make it go back to unity!

Tags: unity, gnome, login

Installed ubuntu 12.10 two days ago, and it works perfectly fine (I'm impressed!).  I wanted to test other desktop environments, so I installed Kubuntu, Gnome3, and Xubuntu.

All of them work fine, but my login screen is now Gnome3 (I preferred Unity).

How can I set the Unity login screen to be the default again?

Comment: Did you remove Unity ?

Comment: No, unity is still there, and i can access it with no problem

Comment: On your login screen, you can change the desktop. Have you tried selecting Ubuntu (2D) Option from the Ubuntu Ring..?

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple one, you just gotta set `lightdm` as default.

Just run `dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` as **root** and choose `lightdm` as default dm.

Answer (score 0):

To switch between desktops `Logout`. At Login Screen you can choose desktop as shown in below figure.

[image]

Comment: That isn't a problem, as the menu works fine. The problem at the moment is my Login screen. The ''Skin'' of the login screen is set to look like Gnome3 when i open my computer. And i would like it to look like Unity by default D: